# Serialization issue on custom type

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have following classes:

```
 [Serializable]
public class TradeBotSettings 
{
    public ExchangePlatform Exchange
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
 [Serializable]
    public enum ExchangePlatform
    {

        [XmlEnum("BTC_E")]
        BTC_E,
        [XmlEnum("BitStamp")]
        BitStamp,
        [XmlEnum("CampBX")]
        CampBX,
        [XmlEnum("Cryptsy")]
        Cryptsy,
        [XmlEnum("BTCChina")]
        BTCChina,
    }
```

When i try to serialize gives error

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             TradeBotSettings tbSettings = new TradeBotSettings();
        tbSettings.Exchange = ExchangePlatform.BTC_E;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Temp\Trader\Trader\Trader\bin\x86\Debug\configs\bots.xml", false);
        xmlSerializerTradebot = new XmlSerializer(tbSettings.GetType());
        xmlSerializerSettings.Serialize(sw, tbSettings);
        sw.Close();
        }
```

Error is : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

This looks like a generic error anyone have a clue about this

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the line `xmlSerializerSettings.Serialize(sw, tbSettings);` a typo? That wont compile.

Comment: dont understand sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you presented wont compile, xmlSerializerSettings is unknown. This probably should have been "xmlSerializerTradebot.Serialize(..." instead, and this works fine. Maybe that´s your problem?

BTW: You should use the "using" clause when creating StreamWriter instances to prevent having the file not immediately closed in case of serialization exceptions. You also dont need to use the XMLEnum attribute unless you want to have the default serialization behaviour for enums changed...

BTW2: Yeah, i know, this is not a clear answer to the problem and i should rather comment. I would if i already could... ;-)

Comment: Yes the line was the problem xmlSerializerTradebot the same as mike noted ty